# Formula for Summing up a Geometric Series with alternate addition and subtraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

Is there a formula to figure of the sum of n terms of the following series where r is a constant.

$S = r^{n-1} - r^{n-2} + r^{n-3} - r^{n-4}\ldots r^0$

For $n=7$,

$S = r^6 - r^5 + r^4 - r^3 + r^2 - r^1 + r^0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider the ratio of the progression as being $-r$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit ? I'm confused because of the alternation

Comment: @helloworld Maybe changing variables will help you. Write $u = -r$ and remember that, for example $(u)^5 = -r^5$.